# Windows Search 4 web interface

Tags: windows, search, search-server

I have Windows Search 4 running on an installation of Server 2008 x64, indexing two specific directories.

Is it possible to have a web interface to query this catalog?

On an older server (Server 2003) we are using the Indexing Service and the following sample to query that index:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692879(VS.85).aspx

This is working perfectly, and we just want to take advantage of the Search 4.0 features/performance in the same web format.

I have looked at Search Server Express and it's not quite what we're looking for. I have also seen a couple references to use the Microsoft.Search.Interop but I don't know how to put it all together in an aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MSFT answered a very similar question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdesktopsearchhelp/thread/46ddf830-0b98-4806-a67a-a0aea5d7bac6). Was the OP you, or does the answer provided helps you?

Comment: That was me, but I don't know how to put it together. I'm sure the answer is in the right direction, but for someone with limited programming/development skills, I still need more of a "push". Even a good tutorial on aspx pages would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really more about general programming then. Have a look at http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/ - there are some really excellent tutoruals on ASP.NET.